# Showing that $R / I$ is a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring and let $I$ be an ideal (that is, $I \le R$ and $R \cdot I \subset I)$. Define $$R / I = \{r + I : r \in R \}$$
>   Show that $R/I$ is a ring under the operations $(r+I) + (s+I) = (r+s)+I$ and $(r+I) \cdot (s+I) = rs + I$.

The hint tells me to show that each operation is well-defined.

Comment: Why do yo want to use the “fundamental theorem of group homomorphisms“?

Comment: I was instructed to show that the function is "well-defined".

Comment: I don't see how using group homomorphisms will allow you to conclude anything about the *ring* structure. This is a straightforward exercise in showing definitions are satisfied! EDIT: well-defined just means that $(x+I) = (x'+I)$, $(y+I) = (y'+I) \Rightarrow (x+I)+(y+I) = (x'+I)+(y'+I)$, and the same for multiplication.

Comment: So obviously the group homomorphisms theorem does not apply here.

Comment: Well a ring is a group with respect to addition, so they might.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very formal way of checking that $R/I$ is a ring.

---

Consider the maps

- $a \colon R × R → R/I,\, (r,s) ↦ (r+s)+I$,
- $m \colon R × R → R/I,\, (r,s) ↦ (r·s)+I$, and
- $π×π \colon R × R → R/I × R/I,\, (r,s) ↦ (r+I,s+I)$

(where $π \colon R → R/I,\, r ↦ r+I$).

Show that

- $∀(r,s) ∈ R × R \colon\quad (r-r',s-s') ∈ I × I ⇒ a(r,s) = a(r',s')$,
- $∀(r,s) ∈ R × R \colon\quad (r-r',s-s') ∈ I × I ⇒ m(r,s) = m(r',s')$, and
- $∀(r,s) ∈ R × R \colon\quad (r-r',s-s') ∈ I × I ⇔ (π×π)(r,s) = (π×π)(r',s')$.

Now, there’s a general theorem saying:

> For any sets $A, B, F$ with a map $f \colon A → B$ and a *surjective* map $p \colon A → F$, if
>   $$∀a,a' ∈ A \colon\quad p(a) = p(a') ⇒ f(a) = f(a'),$$
>   then there is a unique map $\bar{f} \colon F → B$ such that $f = \bar{f}∘π$.

Prove and understand that once and for all. It’s a good idea to use this theorem (as well as the homomorphism theorems for any structures) whenever you need to check whether a map given by representatives is well-defined (representations of elements are usually surjective maps in disguise).

Using this on $p = π×π$ and $f = a$ or $f = m$, it follows that $\bar{a} = +$ and $\bar{m} = ·$ are well-defined maps. Then you need to check the ring axioms, but you can do this by using representatives, exploiting their validity in $R$.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely do the laborious way that @k,stm did, and in fact, such is the most sure-fire way to be correct.  However, seeing as you have (hopefully) been exposed to groups, and quotients of groups, here is what you can do.  (So group stuff is *not* totally irrelevant here).

(I assume $R$ is commutative.  If not, slightly more words are required, but this will do for now)

First, note a particular definition/characterization of what a ring $R$ is:
$R$ is a ring if $(R, +)$ is an Abelian group and there exists a map $R\times R \to R$ sending $(r_1, r_2) \mapsto r_1r_2$ such that $1r = r$, $(rs)t = r(st)$, and $r(r_1 + r_2) = rr_1+rr_2$.  In short, one says that there is an action of $R$ on $R$.  This is really viewing $R$ as a $R$-module.

Well, $I$ being an ideal means that $I$ is a subgroup of $R$ (with respect to $+$), and that $R\cdot I \subset I$ (i.e. $I$ "absorbs" multiplication by $R$).

Hence, we can first view $R/I$ as a quotient group.  This automatically grants us that viewing $R/I$ as cosets of $I$, i.e. $R/I = \{a+I : a\in R\}$, addition is well-defined.  And now, we only need check that $R/I\times R/I\overset{mult}\to R/I$ is well-defined., which follows rather easily from the fact that $I$ "absorbs" multiplication by $R$.

I fear this may not have been as helpful in solving the problem, but to me viewing $R/I$ really as a quotient group with additional multiplication structure (that is what a ring is: an abelian group with mult. structure) has helped me a lot.